# Create directory with ARGV (ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, methods, syntax-error, argv

I created this program to create a folder in the program directory if there is an ARGV.

```
def check_if_user_gave_input
  abort("mkdir: missing input") if ARGV.empty?
end

def get_folder_name
  return folder_name = ARGV.first
end

def create_folder(name)
  Dir.mkdir(name)
end

def perform
  folder_name = get_folder_name
  create_folder(folder_name)
end

perform
```

So, if I run this program in my terminal everything is OK. But, if I try it in my terminal and don't write anything after `$ ruby app.rb` I get a nice error message like this and I don't see the string `"mkdir: missing input"`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from app.rb:18:in `<main>'
    2: from app.rb:15:in `perform'
    1: from app.rb:10:in `create_folder'
app.rb:10:in `mkdir': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

How to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `check_if_user_gave_input` method in `perform`

```
def check_if_user_gave_input
  abort("mkdir: missing input") if ARGV.empty?
end

def get_folder_name
  ARGV.first
end

def create_folder(name)
  Dir.mkdir(name)
end

def perform
  check_if_user_gave_input
  folder_name = get_folder_name
  create_folder(folder_name)
end

perform
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, it had to be put at the start of the perform method ...